# What (jQuery) means in the end of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:

```
var waitingDialog = (function($){
.....
return{
}
})(jQuery);
```

Also could you explain what $ means in the function? Is it going to work without that?

Comment: It's an IIFE taking `jQuery` as a parameter, and that parameter will be called `$` in the scope of the IIFE.

Answer (score 2):

It means that jQuery (if it exists) will be passed to the function.  $ is merely the name that variable will take in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 2):

There is a section about that in official jQuery website : https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope