# What does `function (n) { .. }(jQuery)` mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am examining a minified script and see this pattern `function (n) { .. }(jQuery)` all over the place and it's used in chain like so: `function (n) {..}(jQuery), !function (n) {..}(jQuery), !function (n) {..}(jQuery)`.

Pls note that it's not `(function($) {})(jQuery);` and I couldn't find any answer to my question.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256718/what-jquery-means-in-the-end-of-function

Comment: @daremachine - what I am asking is different, there is no parentheses around `function (n) { .. }`.

Comment: I dont see different. (jQuery) at the end is passed like n because its compiled. $ is more readable than n.

Comment: Without enclosing parentheses (to make an IIFE),  I don't believe this is valid syntax. Can you please give a link to the code you saw this in?

Comment: `function (n) { .. }` is a [function expression](https://medium.com/@mandeep1012/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions-b43646042052) which lets you map a function to a variable. `function (n) { .. }(x)` immediately invokes the function.

Comment: That is, for the first one. With the initial `!` it's perfectly valid as an IIFE. The key is to have some token before the `function` keyword to make it a function expression, rather than a function declaration.

Comment: @max that's true, but JS will parse any statement beginning with the word `function` as a function declaration, not an expression - anything coming after the closing `}` on the same line is invalid syntax. That's exactly why IIFE's always have enclosing parentheses, or sometimes a leading `!` - they're both "tricks" to make the engine parse it as an expression.

Comment: @RobinZigmond - here is a part of the script https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-keller-wbtm5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. Please ignore the start and end of that. Thank you!

Comment: `!function(n){}` and `(function(n){})` have the same effect so they can be considered equivalent for all intents and purposes. Hence the answers given on the linked question (and its duplicates) should answer yours. Particularly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23925102/218196

Comment: @FelixKling - didn't know they're equivalent. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a function expression that's immediately called, which is more commonly known as an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

The brackets are of course because *this* wouldn't work:

```js
function(){}();
```

As that's invalid JavaScript. Following this, prepending the IIFE with the `!` character allows missing out the prefix `(` and suffix `)`, and is of course done by a minifer in most cases.